# How to automated a email trigger in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

My web application need to send email at particular time , i have completed the other parts like fetching data from SQL Server and sending it via email but the next step is to automate it to send email every day at particular time (example 5AM PST). Is it possible in an ASP.NET Core web applications to call an action method every day automatically without we manually click a button or trigger a event?

Thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use IHostedService like this:

```
public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private Timer _timer;

    public TimedHostedService()
    {
        //Some DI here...
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        //this will trigger DoWork every minute
        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, 
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
        //Every time when DoWork is triggered you can check time that you need
        var start = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 0);
        var end = new TimeSpan(15, 0, 59);
        var now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        if(start <= now && end <= now)
        {
            //send emails
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
       _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

       return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You can find more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Pay close attention to this:

> The Timer doesn't wait for previous executions of DoWork to finish, so the approach shown might not be suitable for every scenario.

You need your emails sent only once, so it is important to adjust timer interval and time check in DoWork accordingly so you wouldn't send emails twice.

Comment: Thank you for sharing,  Will give a try

Comment: It Worked , Thank you